# React Native Dimensions not working on rotation

Tags: react-native

I am running the code posted (for Class Component) at:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions

Yet, at the Android Studio simulator, If I  "rotate" the device the dimension's values do not change i.e. I was expecting that the height and width could change with the rotation but this is not happening. Any ideas why?

According to the info posted at the previous link it says:

*Although dimensions are available immediately, they may change (e.g **due to device rotation**, foldable devices etc) so any rendering logic or styles that depend on these constants should try to call this function on every render, rather than caching the value (for example, using inline styles rather than setting a value in a StyleSheet).*

I also tried using using useWindowDimensions but this is limited to functional react components.

So far, I can not find a reliable way to detect if an Android device rotated using React-Native and class components :-(

Note: This problem also happens with React Function Component

Comment: This is a known bug with the Dimensions module on Android.
You can track it here - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29323

Comment: This bug was carried to RN 0.64 from 0.63.... oh boy!

Comment: You can apparently use a safe area hook as an alternative to the Dimensions module, please check the link to the suggestion on the same thread below - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29323#issuecomment-801165454

Answer (score 5):

Try: https://reactnative.dev/docs/usewindowdimensions
It works for me

```
import { useWindowDimensions } from 'react-native';


const { height, width } = useWindowDimensions();
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Upgrading `react-native` to version **`0.64.2`** fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

My problem on 0.61.5 was not that the values were not correct, but that the view was not re-rendered at all after the rotation, so I added this to the constructor() and it worked:

```
Dimensions.addEventListener('change', () => {
  this.setState({});
});
```